# xml attribute what to be working

Tags: php, xml

I have a function that show a result but its not working this the source code

```
function push($element, $addchild, $attributes = array()) {
    $this->_indent();
    $this->xml .= '<'.$element;
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
        $this->xml .= ' '.$key.'="'.htmlentities($value).'"';
    }
    $this->xml .= ">\n";
    $this->stack[] = $element;
}
```

The result is `<listing_Last_update>` in XML

I want the result like this `<listing last_update="2014-08-08 14:15:16">` can you help me in this matter.

Comment: i want to result like <listing last_update="2014-08-08 14:15:16"> for xml

Comment: please help me..i am very new about xml <listing last_update="2014-08-08 14:15:16">